# Alert Box MVC c#

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, model-view-controller, alert

I've a dude. how to show an alert in MVC? I'm validating from **Controller** the next:

```
var suscriptor = c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud);
                if (suscriptor.Count <= 0)
                {
                    ViewBag.Alert = "Lo sentimos, esta solicitud no existe.";
                    return View("Index");
                }
```

That list is loaded with SQL data. I would like that message to be seen in a PopUp or Alert, preferably in an alert. The Index has a TextBox and a Button.

**Index:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Inicio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Estilos/inicio.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/JavaScript/validar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div class="topnav" style="width: 350px">
            <a title="Providus S.A" href="http://www.providus.com.ar"><img src="~/Images/00.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 350px">
            <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Pdf", "Home")">
                <label for="solicitud">Solicitud: </label>
                <input type="text" id="solicitud" minlength="5" maxlength="7" name="solicitud" placeholder="Solicitud..." required
                       title="Sólo letras y números. Cantidad mínima de caracteres: 5. Cantidad máxima de caracteres: 7"
                       onkeypress="return soloLetrasYnumeros(event)">

                <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </center>
    @if (ViewBag.Alert != null)
            {
                <div class="alert">
                    <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
                    <strong>Providus informa: </strong>
                    <p>@ViewBag.Alert</p>
                </div>
            }
    @*<center>
        <p class="mensaje">@ViewData["Mensaje"]</p>
    </center>*@
```

But i obtain this:

[image]

And what I want is this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of alert box comes from javascript and not form razor, if i'm not wrong.

You may need to make a ajax call to the controller you need in the onload jquery and give it as alert. Something of this kind

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {
               var Student = {  
                    ID: '10001',  
                    Name: 'Shashangka',  
                    Age: 31  
                };  
                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "/Home/JqAJAX",  
                    data: JSON.stringify(Student),  
                    dataType: "json"  
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',  
                    success: function(data) {  
                        alert(data.msg);  
                    },  
                    error: function() {  
                        alert("Error occured!!")  
                    }  
                });  
            });  
</script>
```

or you may try this (i havent tried, but this may work)

```
@if (ViewBag.Alert!= null)  
    {  
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            window.onload = function () {  
                alert("@ViewBag.Alert");  
            };  
        </script>  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the second way works perfect. Thank you so much :)